# Add link to Angular material DataTable

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm working in Angular Material Data Table, and I want to add `Edit` link to each row of table, so I do:

```
  <ng-container matColumnDef="action">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
              Action
            </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user">
              <a href="#/categorias/usuarios/detalle/' +
                 {{user.id}} +
                  '" class="m-portlet__nav-link btn m-btn m-btn--hover-accent m-btn--icon m-btn--icon-only m-btn--pill">
                <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
              </a>
            </mat-cell>
          </ng-container>
```

But it just no work, first it is not a link, chrome debugger throw it as:

```
<a class="m-portlet__nav-link btn m-btn m-btn--hover-accent m-btn--icon m-btn--icon-only m-btn--pill" ng-reflect-href="#/categorias/usuarios/detalle/">
                <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
              </a>
```

What am I doing wrong? why is not href link, and why isn't have id of row? Regards

Comment: Create stackblitz for that.

Answer (score 1):

This will work

```
<a href="#/categorias/usuarios/detalle/{{user.id}}" class="m-portlet__nav-link btn m-btn m-btn--hover-accent m-btn--icon m-btn--icon-only m-btn--pill">
```

Also check if `user.id` is set. It will give similar output if `user.id` is `undefined` or `null` or empty string. My examples covers 2 of those.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ko8uwa

Comment: That's so extrange, I just keep geting a like: `<a class="m-portlet__nav-link btn m-btn m-btn--hover-accent m-btn--icon m-btn--icon-only m-btn--pill" ng-reflect-href="#/categorias/usuarios/detalle/"></a>` something can hapen with material datattable?

Comment: Stackblitz proofs it works. Nothing related to angular material

Comment: It is also possible that `user.id===undefined` and it will be ommited.

Comment: I don't know why my api changes `a href` for a `ng-reflect-href` in chrome console it's so extrange  `<a ng-reflect-href="#/categorias/usuarios/detalle/"></a>` I modified another [stackblitz](https://angular-8dpwye.stackblitz.io)   and it works, but into my api it doesn't

Comment: 1) Link is pasted badly- its broken now 2) paste link to editor

Comment: `ng-reflect` is just debug information. It wont be present in production build.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8dpwye-a7pwbe still works with binding syntax `[href]`

Comment: I even included your markup to demonstrate that its invalid anyway.